# Ruby On Rails - Redirecting passing the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

noob talking here...

I need some help to understand what's wrong.

I have a Controller (Home) that has 3 views, Index, Tech and Seller. The index view is only to check the current_user action so it's defined like this:

```
  def index
    if current_user.has_role? :tech
      home_tech_path
    elsif current_user.has_role? :sell
      home_seller_path
    end
  end
```

In the application layout I have a link that will change if the user is logged on or not:

```
<'a href= <% if user_signed_in? %><%= ('home/index') %><% else %><%= root_path %><%end%>
```

So, when the user is logged on it should redirect to home/index and in case the user is a :tech, redirect to home/tech in case it's a sell redirect to home/seller. But it's only redirecting to home/index. It looks like it's not minding the HomeController. What am I doing wrong?

---SOLVED---

Just changed on the HomeController to:

```
if current_user.has_role? :tech
  redirect_to('/hometech')
elsif current_user.has_role? :sell
  redirect_to('/homeseller')
end
```

instead of the original

```
def index
    if current_user.has_role? :tech
      home_tech_path
    elsif current_user.has_role? :sell
      home_seller_path
    end
end
```

and on the routes.rb :

```
match '/hometech', to: 'home#tech', via: 'get'
match '/homeseller', to: 'home#seller', via: 'get'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix your issue or not but it's generally not best practice to format your erb tags like that. Instead, try something like:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to "Home", home_tech_path %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
<%end%>
```

Calling `home_tech_path` or `home_seller_path` in the controller just returns the url to that specific route as a string, and you are not using that for anything. If you want to redirect to those specific pages you will need:

```
def index
  if current_user.has_role? :tech
    redirect_to home_tech_path
  elsif current_user.has_role? :sell
    redirect_to home_seller_path
  end
end
```

You might want to read through this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question... The Home is different whether the user is a Tech or a Sell (this are roles). The Index on the HomeController is only to check the user's role and redirect to the matching Homepage. It was working properly if I typed on the address bar home/index but now it's not working using the hyperlink on the application layout...